# How to place toolbar - PyQt4

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, windows-10, python-3.5

How do I place toolbar at the right/left side of the screen. I tried to use:

`self.formatbar = self.addToolBar("Format")
 self.formatbar.setAllowedAreas(Qt.RightToolBarArea)`

I am not getting any errors but the toolbar is still at the top.

Comment: Is it in a `QMainWindow`? "This property only makes sense if the toolbar is in a `QMainWindow`." - Qt Docs on `setAllowedAreas`

Comment: Yes it is in `QMainWindow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setAllowedAreas` defines the area the toolbar is *allowed* to be when it's being dragged around by the user (the default is `Qt.AllToolBarAreas` so you may still want to change this). To actually place it at a specific side, you need to specify it when you add it. For example:

```
self.formatbar = QToolBar() 
self.addToolBar( Qt.LeftToolBarArea , self.formatbar )
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for help for this same issue and came across two Stack Overflow questions on the topic (which includes this one).

As I was testing out the suggested code, I stumbled on what seems to be a suitable solution.

```
tool_bar.setStyleSheet("font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; border-top: none; margin-top: 10px;")
```

You may examine my code to get a better understanding of what I was trying to achieve. I placed headers between the MenuBar and ToolBar lines of code help locate the line(s) you wish to see.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


font = QFont("Arial", 12)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 | Positioning the ToolBar")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("IMAGES II/PyQt5_Icon.ico"))
        self.setFont(font)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000000")
        self.resize(1250, 750)
        self.gui()

    def gui(self):

        self.widgets()
        self.center_window()
        self.show()

    def widgets(self):

        # ==================== Creating the MenuBar ====================

        menu_bar = self.menuBar()
        menu_bar.setStyleSheet("font-size: 12pt; color: #716E6E")

        # ==================== Create the MenuBar Items ====================

        file_menu = menu_bar.addMenu("File")
        edit_menu = menu_bar.addMenu("Edit")
        view_menu = menu_bar.addMenu("View")
        synchronize_menu = menu_bar.addMenu("Synchronize")
        window_menu = menu_bar.addMenu("Window")
        help_menu = menu_bar.addMenu("Help")

        # ==================== Create the File Menu's Submenus and Menu Items ====================

        # Create the Submenu(s):
        file_submenu = QMenu("New", self)
        file_submenu.setStyleSheet("font-size: 12pt; color: #716E6E")

        file_properties_submenu = QMenu("File Properties", self)
        file_properties_submenu.setStyleSheet("font-size: 12pt; color: #716E6E")

        # This is a submenu within the file_properties_submenu
        line_separators = QMenu("Line Separators", self)
        line_separators.setStyleSheet("font-size: 12pt; color: #716E6E")

        # Create file_submenu Items:
        new_file = QAction("New File", self)
        directory = QAction("Directory", self)
        python_file = QAction("Python File", self)
        html_file = QAction("HTML File", self)
        open = QAction("Open", self)
        save_as = QAction("Save as", self)
        settings = QAction("Settings", self)
        exit = QAction("Exit", self)
        exit.triggered.connect(self.close_app)

        # Add Items to file_submenu Submenu:
        file_submenu.addAction(new_file)
        file_submenu.addAction(directory)
        file_submenu.addSeparator()
        file_submenu.addAction(python_file)
        file_submenu.addAction(html_file)

        # Create file_properties_submenu Items:
        file_encoding = QAction("File Encoding", self)
        remove_bom = QAction("Remove BOM", self)
        add_bom = QAction("Add BOM", self)
        associate_with_file_type = QAction("Associate with File Type", self)

        # Create line_separators_submenu Items:
        crlf_windows = QAction("CRLF - Windows", self)
        lf_unix_and_macos = QAction("LF - Unix and macos", self)
        cs_classic_macos = QAction("CS - Classic macos", self)

        # Add Items to line_separatos submenu:
        line_separators.addAction(crlf_windows)
        line_separators.addAction(lf_unix_and_macos)
        line_separators.addAction(cs_classic_macos)

        # Add Items and Submenus to file_properties_submenu:
        file_properties_submenu.addAction(file_encoding)
        file_properties_submenu.addAction(remove_bom)
        file_properties_submenu.addAction(add_bom)
        file_properties_submenu.addSeparator()
        file_properties_submenu.addAction(associate_with_file_type)
        file_properties_submenu.addMenu(line_separators)

        # Add Submenus and Menu Items to File Menu:
        file_menu.addMenu(file_submenu)
        file_menu.addAction(open)
        file_menu.addAction(save_as)
        file_menu.addSeparator()
        file_menu.addAction(settings)
        file_menu.addMenu(file_properties_submenu)
        file_menu.addSeparator()
        file_menu.addAction(exit)

        # ==================== Edit Menu Submenus and Menu Items ====================

        # Create Menu Items:
        undo_ = QAction("Undo", self)
        redo_ = QAction("Redo", self)
        cut_ = QAction("Cut", self)
        copy_ = QAction("Copy", self)
        paste_ = QAction("Paste", self)

        # Add Menu Items to Edit Menu:
        edit_menu.addAction(undo_)
        edit_menu.addAction(redo_)
        edit_menu.addSeparator()
        edit_menu.addAction(cut_)
        edit_menu.addAction(copy_)
        edit_menu.addAction(paste_)


        # ==================== Creating a Vertical ToolBar ====================

        # Create the ToolBar
        tool_bar = self.addToolBar("")

        # Position the ToolBar on the left side of the Main Window
        self.addToolBar(Qt.LeftToolBarArea, tool_bar)

        # Prevent the User from moving the ToolBar
        tool_bar.setMovable(False)

        # Enable descriptive text to be displayed under the
        # ToolButton Icons
        tool_bar.setToolButtonStyle(Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)

        # Set font family, font size, and color of text for ToolBar Buttons
        tool_bar.setStyleSheet("font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; border-top: none; margin-top: 10px")

        # Set the size of the ToolButton Icons
        tool_bar.setIconSize(QSize(35, 35))

        # Create ToolBar item-icons with text
        python_tool_bar_btn = QAction(QtGui.QIcon("IMAGES I/python.png"), "Python", self)
        python_tool_bar_btn.setToolTip("Python Programming")

        c_tool_bar_btn = QAction(QtGui.QIcon("IMAGES I/c-file.png"), "C", self)
        c_tool_bar_btn.setToolTip("C Programming")

        java_tool_bar_btn = QAction(QtGui.QIcon("IMAGES I/java.png"), "Java", self)
        java_tool_bar_btn.setToolTip("Java Programming")

        javascript_tool_bar_btn = QAction(QtGui.QIcon("IMAGES I/javascript.png"), "Javascript", self)
        javascript_tool_bar_btn.setToolTip("Javascript Programming")

        swift_tool_bar_btn = QAction(QtGui.QIcon("IMAGES I/swift.png"), "Swift", self)
        swift_tool_bar_btn.setToolTip("Swift Programming")

        stack_overflow_tool_bar_btn = QAction(QtGui.QIcon("IMAGES I/stack-overflow.png"), "Stack\nOverflow", self)
        stack_overflow_tool_bar_btn.setToolTip("Stack Overflow")

        # Add item-icons to ToolBar
        tool_bar.addAction(python_tool_bar_btn)
        tool_bar.addAction(c_tool_bar_btn)
        tool_bar.addAction(java_tool_bar_btn)
        tool_bar.addAction(javascript_tool_bar_btn)
        tool_bar.addAction(swift_tool_bar_btn)
        tool_bar.addAction(stack_overflow_tool_bar_btn)

        # Define a single function that provides functionality
        # to all the ToolBar item-icons
        tool_bar.actionTriggered.connect(self.tool_bar_actions)

    def tool_bar_actions(self, tool_bar_btn):
        if tool_bar_btn.text() == "Python":
            print("Python and PyQt5 GUI Programming")

        elif tool_bar_btn.text() == "C":
            print("C Programming")

        elif tool_bar_btn.text() == "Java":
            print("Java Programming")

        elif tool_bar_btn.text() == "Javascript":
            print("Javascript Programming")

        elif tool_bar_btn.text() == "Swift":
            print("Swift Programming")

        else:
            print("Stack Overflow Developer's Community")

    def close_app(self):
        self.close()

    def center_window(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())


def main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)

    App.setStyleSheet(
        """
        
        QMenuBar { background-color: #000000; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: #0476B3; }
        
        QMenuBar::item:selected { background-color: #c8e5ff; color: #0476B3; }
        
        QMenu::item:selected { background-color: #c8e5ff; color: #0476B3; }
        
        """
    )

    main_window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Example ToolBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMSx9.jpg)